# xterm windows not displayed after vnc

Tags: vnc, xterm

When I create vnc for my linux box, its showing desktop when I login. I want only xterm windows. I see xterm under /bin/xterm. Please help.

Comment: could you clarify your question please. It is not clear what you want to achieve

Comment: I need to be only seeing xterm window. I see shared desktop from utlra vnc. After I create a client, and login from client I see server desktop. I want to see only xterm window, which is like terminal.

Comment: How did you start your xvnc server?

Comment: >vncserver, one command

Comment: Or how to attach xterm to xvnc, I need to switch off desktop. I need only xterm

Comment: Are you sure you are connecting your VNC client to the display/port belonging to your vncserver instance, rather than to the previously existing "physical" desktop running on the machine? If it's not a headless server, then you will probably need to adjust the VNC client connection to connect to a higher display / port e.g. `:1` or `:5901` in place of the default `:0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to edit file  $HOME/.vnc/xstartup with the contents below:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
# unset SESSION_MANAGER
# exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
xterm -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
#twm &
/opt/fvwm/bin/fvwm2 &
```

This will turn off desktop and show only xterm windows.